# Error deleting items from a two dimensional array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The following code successfully populates a table of `Cars` and groups them by `Category` what I haven't been able to do is delete the last item from a section. When there are multiple items I can successfully delete all of them except for the last one; on the last one I get an error.

### CODE

```
class Car{
    var make = ""
    var model = ""
    var category = ""
    var isActive = false
    
    init(make:String, model:String, category:String, isActive:Bool) {
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.category = category
        self.isActive = isActive
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!    
    
    var carsFromRealmDatabase:[Car] = [Car(make:"Ford", model:"Mustang", category: "Sport", isActive: false),
                    Car(make:"Ford", model:"Escort", category: "Sport", isActive: false),
                    Car(make:"Chevy", model:"Camaro", category: "Sedan", isActive: false),
                    Car(make:"Volkswagen", model:"Jetta", category: "Sedan", isActive: false),
                    Car(make:"Tesla", model:"Model S", category: "Sporty", isActive: false),
                    Car(make:"Tesla", model:"Cybertruck", category: "Pickup", isActive: false),]
    
    var sections : [[Car]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createSectionsFromCars()
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].model
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section][0].category
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        //  DELETE action
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, index in
            self.carsFromRealmDatabase.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.createSectionsFromCars()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            self.myTable.reloadData()
        }
        return [delete]
    }
    
    func createSectionsFromCars(){
        // temporary Dictionary to be able to group cars by category.
        var sectionForCategory:Dictionary = [String: [Car]]()
        
        // add groups of arrays from Dictionary to sections array.
        for car in carsFromRealmDatabase {
            if sectionForCategory[car.category] == nil {
                sectionForCategory[car.category] = []
            }
            sectionForCategory[car.category]!.append(car)
        }
        sections = sectionForCategory.keys.sorted().map({ sectionForCategory[$0]! })
    }
}
```

### ERROR

> Thread 1: Exception: "Invalid update: invalid number of sections.
> The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (4),
> plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted)."

In `Image 1` I was able to delete `Escort` without a problem but in `Image 2` I got an error trying to deleting `Mustang`.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: When you remove the last row from a section you need to remove that array from your `sections` array and delete the section from your tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paulw11 suggested in his comment you're missing handler for section deletion.
So after playing a little bit with your code I ended up with something like this for `editActionsForRowAt` method:

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        //  DELETE action
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, index in
            self.sections[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)

            if self.sections[indexPath.section].count == 0 {
                self.sections.remove(at: indexPath.section)

                let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: indexPath.section)
                tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
            } else {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath],
                                     with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            }
        }
        return [delete]
    }
```

Where I replaced manipulation of `carsFromRealmDatabase` and added deletion handlers from the `sections` directly